# Formatting a datagridview column to display formatted datetime instead of serial datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, datatable

I load a `DataTable` with the results of a SQL query, such as 'Select * From Table'. A few of the columns are a date/time stamp in serial and is regarded in the `DataTable` as a `double`, e.g. 20170613103015, These columns are also have "Date" in the column name.

After this I set a `DataGridView` data source as the DataTable, what I am wondering is, if I can then format these date/time stamp as an actual datetime, if so how?

I realize that this doesn't work but at least shows what the format I'm after is.

```
dgvAssets.DataSource = rowData.asset_table;

for (int c = 0; c < dgvAssets.Columns.Count; c++)
{
    if (dgvAssets.Columns[c].Name.Contains("DATE") && dgvAssets.Columns[c].ValueType == typeof(double))
    {
        dgvAssets.Columns[c].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not store datetime information as double value in the db. If you can fix that you have fixed this too. If you can't fix that then you have to do string operation to identify datetime components from this value to get actual DateTime value created.

Comment: No unfortunately changing the double datatype in the db is out of my control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CellFormating event:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == Datecolumn.Index && e.Value !=null)
        {
            e.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToInt64(e.Value).ToString(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
```

Formatting double to DateTime is an example. I do not know if this is your format of date. You can also modify condition `e.ColumnIndex == Datecolumn.Index` so it would be good for all of your columns (e.g. check if index in in some kind of array/list of valid indexes)

Comment: Brilliant just what I was looking for, the other answers were great as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to fix the datatable :

```
DataTable asset_table = rowData.asset_table;

int colCount = asset_table.Columns.Count;
for (int col = colCount - 1; colCount >= 0; colCount--)
{
    string colName = asset_table.Columns[col].ColumnName;
    if (colName.Contains("DATE"))
    {
        asset_table.Columns.Add("Temp Col", typeof(DateTime));
        foreach (DataRow row in asset_table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(((double)row[colName]).ToString(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            row["Temp Col"] = date;
        }
        asset_table.Columns.Remove(colName);
        asset_table.Columns["Temp Col"].ColumnName = colName;
        asset_table.Columns[colName].SetOrdinal(col);
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed string to double and back.

Answer (score 1):

use the `CellFormatting` event to manuplate value for view.
first collect the relevant column indexs, then add `CellFormatting` event (i did it a lambda to capture `colsDate` variable)

```
dgvAssets.DataSource = rowData.asset_table;

int[] colsDate = dataGridView1.Columns
                              .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                              .Where(col => col.Name.Contains("DATA"))
                              .Select(col => col.Index)
                              .ToArray();


dataGridView1.CellFormatting += (s, e) =>
{
    if (colsDate.Contains(e.ColumnIndex))
    {
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Value.ToString(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        e.Value = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
};

//this its necessary if you want allow user edit the cell, and take the value back to db double format.

dataGridView1.CellParsing += (s, e) =>
{
    if (colsDate.Contains(e.ColumnIndex))
    {
        var date = DateTime.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Value = double.Parse(date.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"));
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: won't work because date is not a standard date time format.  Need to use ParseExact().

Comment: @jdweng thank! and the true answer It is your ... but both answers will have a problem updating the data. need as a wpf-converter...

Answer (score 1):

I can offer another method, completely different from those already proposed.

Do the data conversion in the sql query.

Instead of a `select *` query write the query, indicating all columns. During which converting the necessary columns to `datetime`.

Something like this:

```
select id
     , convert(datetime, format(SomeDate1, '####-##-## ##:##:##'))
     , convert(datetime, format(SomeDate2, '####-##-## ##:##:##'))
from Table
```

Assuming you are using Sql Server.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, it is definitely another solution, however in my case i don't want to worry about updating the columns each time the db changes